# add UIImageView that covers navigation bar

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiimageview

I think I'm missing something simple here. I need to create a semi-transparent UIImageView that covers the entire screen including the navigation toolbar. How do I do this?

This is what I'm trying to do ...

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a possible solution:

```
UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"whatever.png"];
UIImageView *overlay=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
overlay.alpha=0.5;
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:overlay];
```

EDIT:

- It is likely that you would not be setting the alpha value for the overlay, but rather use a transparent PNG with embedded transparence levels. Still, it's a possibility.
- When not using ARC, you should `[overlay release]`.

Comment: Default.png is a bit of a weird file to choose for an example like this.. The last line is not necessary, addSubview puts the new subview on top of all the other subviews.

Comment: I haven't tried this but I'm guessing I won't be able to detect rotation.

Comment: @Eric, this code will not prevent you from detecting rotation, nor it will help you: it's up to you to detect the current interface/device rotation and select and place your overlay image accordingly.

Comment: @Daan, given the experience level of the original question, I tried to offer a compact example that is likely to work when dropped into an XCode project. Your comments are valid, but you're of course experienced.

Comment: Experience has nothing to do with providing a good example. `Default.png` is a bad name as that used to be the name reserved for the apps icon file. Adding superflous code such as `[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] bringSubviewToFront:overlay];` does not add value and just means that the user wil likely include superflous code in their projects from now on because someone suggested it and it worked.

Comment: @Paul, Default.png has never been reserved for an *icon file*.

Comment: I stand corrected it was used to indicate the file to be used as the loading screen. This would still present the same issue regardless.

Comment: @Paul you are right - I have altered the answer to reflect your observations.

Comment: in addition to this nice solution i had the problem to dismiss the view with a tap but prevent that tap from activating any control in the superview/navigation bar. I found this solution:

`[[overlayView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setUserInteractionEnabled:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:FALSE]];
        [overlayView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];`

Answer (score 1):

To focus the above answer a little bit, you just need to be clear on how views clip to what parts of the device's screen that they "own".

The key point is that in a navigation view, the Navigation bar itself is not part of your `[myController view]` - your view controller's view is everything below the bar and anything you do in that view clips to the rectangle below that bar.

The bar is, however, part of your `[myAppDelegate window]`.  The window is essentially the entire screen of your device, while the views are sub portions responsible for managing their specific bounds.  So calling `[[myAppDelegate window] addSubView:]` will display above the bar where `[[myViewController view] addSubView:]` will not.